# Wordpress image from assets/img folder does not show

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress and i just manually add an **image** to the `assets/img` folder inside a **theme folder**.

After i just reference the image in the code :

```
echo '<img src="'. TEMPLATE_URL .'/assets/img/my-thumb.jpg" alt="">';
```

The image **does not show**, even the image is there inside the folder.

Seems like an extra step is needed, so the image can be seen.

Is there a way to show the image ?

Comment: where fo you take `TEMPLATE_URL ` constant from ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually i use `get_template_directory_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` on child theme